# Need to associate two lists in Python

Tags: python

I am working on an assignment in Python and need to associate rainfall amounts with each month. I need to print the low and high months for rainfall, but the way my code is currently written I can only print the actual amount, but not the month that corresponds with the amount. I think I would associate the two under the enter_rainfall function, but am not sure how to go about associating the two. 
Any advice is appreciated.

```
def main():

    months_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    rain = enter_rainfall()
    average = avg_rainfall(rain)
    lowhigh = low_High(rain)
    print(format(average, '.2f'))

def enter_rainfall():
    rain_fall = []
    months = 12

    for months_list in range(months):
        rain_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount of rain:',))
        rain_fall.append(rain_amount)



    return(rain_fall)


def avg_rainfall(rain):
    total = 0

    for value in rain:
        total += value
    average = total / len(rain)
    return(average)

def low_High(rain, months_list):
    low = min(rain)
    month = months_list[rain.index(low)]
    print(month)
    high = max(rain)
    print(high)





main()
```

Comment: Is the problem a runtime error? If so, I think the problem is just that `months_list` is local to `main`. Take it out of the function body, and your code should work using the call in `low_High`

Comment: @c2huc2hu No the code works, but the way it is working right now it is returning the min and max rainfall amounts, but i need to associate each month with a rainfall amount to then return the month associated with lowest and highest rainfall amounts.

Comment: No it doesn't, I just ran it and it gives a runtime error. After fixing it, `print(month)` does the right thing. Ben's answer is correct though

Comment: @c2huc2hu  sorry about that. Code did work prior to me rearranging it in attempt to pull min and max months

Answer (score 1):

When you call `low_High`, you're not actually passing in your list of months (`month_list`).  Instead, you should call it as such: `low_High(rain, months_list)`.  When you print your minimum and maximum, you probably want to print both the month and the value-- right now, you print the month with the minimum and the value of the maximum.

```
def low_High(rain, months_list):
    low_val = min(rain)
    low_month = months_list[rain.index(low_val)]
    high_val = max(rain)
    high_month = months_list[rain.index(high_val)]
    print('{month} had the least amount of rain with {val}'.format(month=low_month, val=low_val))
    print('{month} had the most amount of rain with {val}'.format(month=high_month, val=high_val))
```

If you want to keep track of the months as you prompt the user, you can access the array as you loop over it by modifying `enter_rainfall`:

```
def main():
...        
    rain = enter_rainfall(month_list)
...

def enter_rainfall(month_list)
    for month in month_list:
        rain_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount of rain for {month}:'.format(month=month),))
        rain_fall.append(rain_amount)
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the response it was very helpful. I had one additional question regarding my code. For the enter_rainfall method is it possible to utilize the months_list so that the user knows what month they are entering rainfall for?

Comment: @Temple90 Please consider marking one of the answers accepted (using the checkmark on the left).

Comment: @Temple90 edited my answer to answer your second question as well

Answer (score 1):

You could set up a *dictionary* that will log the rain with corresponding month, then you can find the `min` and `max` using the *dictionary* `values` and the associated month using the `keys`

```
def enter_rainfall():
    months_list = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December']
    rain_fall = {i: 0 for i in months_list}

    for k in rain_fall:
        rain_fall[k] += float(input('Please enter the amount of rain for {}: '.format(k)))

    return rain_fall

def low_High(dicta):
    all_rain = [v for v in dicta.values()]
    low = ([k for k in dicta if dicta[k] == min(all_rain)], min(all_rain))
    high = ([k for k in dicta if dicta[k] == max(all_rain)], max(all_rain))
    return low, high

x = enter_rainfall()
low, high = low_High(x)
print(low, high)
```

> ```
> Please enter the amount of rain for January: 10
> Please enter the amount of rain for February: 11
> Please enter the amount of rain for March: 12
> Please enter the amount of rain for April: 10
> Please enter the amount of rain for May: 22
> Please enter the amount of rain for June: 18
> Please enter the amount of rain for July: 1
> Please enter the amount of rain for August: 9
> Please enter the amount of rain for September: 2 
> Please enter the amount of rain for October: 22
> Please enter the amount of rain for November: 8
> Please enter the amount of rain for December: 10
> (['July'], 1.0) (['May', 'October'], 22.0)
> ```

In case of two or more months with the same rainfall as `max` or `min` all corresponding months are returned in a list

Answer (score 0):

The `print` and `return` could accept multiple return and print string. You don't need to restrain the number.

You just need to change `main` like that.

```
def enter_rainfall():
    rain_fall = []
    months = 12

    for months_list in range(months):
        rain_amount = float(input('Please enter the amount of rain:',))
        rain_fall.append(rain_amount)
        print(months_list,rain_amount)
        # it will print corresponding month and its rain amount.


    return(rain_fall)
```